How to extend the @TypeConverter for Room database or does it required to extend?
I have a data class:
@Parcelize
data class Task(
    var task: String,
    var done: Boolean = false
) : Parcelable

and corresponding type converters for my Room database:
object Converters {

    ...

    @TypeConverter
    fun tasksToJson(list: List<Task>): String {
        val objects = list.map { item ->
            val jsonObject = JSONObject()
            jsonObject.put("task", item.task)
            jsonObject.put("done", item.done)
        }
        return JSONArray(objects).toString()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToTasks(json: String): List<Task> {
        val iterable = JSONArray(json).iterable<JSONObject>()
        return iterable.map { jsonObject ->
            Task(jsonObject.getString("task"), jsonObject.getBoolean("done"))
        }
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun <T> JSONArray.iterable(): Iterable<T> {
        return Iterable {
            object : Iterator<T> {
                var nextIndex = 0

                override fun next(): T {
                    val element = get(nextIndex)
                    nextIndex++
                    return element as T
                }

                override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
                    return nextIndex < length()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Everything is fine, but I want to extend my data class so that each Task would have a sub task. This is how I extend the data class:
@Parcelize
data class Task(
    var task: String,
    var done: Boolean = false,
    var subTasks: List<Task> = emptyList() // -> sub tasks based on the same data class
) : Parcelable

So the question is, do I need to extend the type converter for sub tasks too? If yes, how do I get it done?

What is "Alonnisos" and how does it relate to this question?

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.


So the question is, do I need to extend the type converter for sub tasks too? If yes, how do I get it done?

The answer is probably No, but this depends upon the respective @Entity annotated class.
In summary, if the Task, whether or not it contains the list of subtasks, is not embedded then the TypeConverter should be sufficient as the List<Task> is part of the Task object that is stored/retrieved (converted by the TypeConverter pair).
However, if the Task is embedded with the @Embedded annotation, then; when before the addition of the subtask list all the fields were types that Room could handle, but after; the
subtaskList<Task> field/member, as it becomes a column in it's own right, would need a TypeConverter pair.
More specifically
An @Entity annotated class, if one of the entities in the entities parameter of the @Database annotation, determines the columns of the table.
If an object that requires a type converter is directly a field/member of the class then that field/member will be a column in it's own right. If that field/member is not one the types that can be directly handled by Room then it will need a pair of TypeConverter functions/methods to convert the object into a type that can be handled by Room.
e.g. If you had:-
@Entity
data class TheTable(
   @PrimaryKey
   val id: Long?=null,
   val something: String,
   val task: Task
}

Then the task field/member equates to a column named task, the underlying value is an object that would need a TypeConverter pair to convert the Task object into/from a value that can be stored in the SQLite database.
The table in the database would be created using  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TheTable (idINTEGER,somethingTEXT NOT NULL,task TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)). i.e. the columns would be:-

id id (integer type (Long Int Byte, even Boolean) is handled by Room and given an SQLite type of INTEGER)

something (String type which equates to SQLite type TEXT)

task (as task is a type of Task, Room doesn't know what to do! However, as a TypeConverter is provided that returned a String then the SQLite type of TEXT is assigned).

The Type Converters, for simplicity of generating the answer were useless (data wise) @TypeConverter fun cnvTaskToString(task: Task): String = "" (which will convert the Task to "")



However, if you instead had:-
@Entity
data class TheTable(
   @PrimaryKey
   val id: Long?=null,
   val something: String,
   @Embedded
   val task: Task
}

Then the table would be created using CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TheTable (idINTEGER,somethingTEXT NOT NULL,taskTEXT NOT NULL,done INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) i.e. columns:-

id (integer type (Long Int Byte, even Boolean) is handled by Room and given an SQLite type of INTEGER)
something (String type which equates to SQLite type TEXT)
task (as the task field/member of the Task object is a String then TEXT)
done (as done is a Boolean then SQlite type INTEGER)

i.e. The fields of the Task object have been copied from the Task object. As in the given example, the fields/members are types that can be handled then no TypeConverters are needed.
However, if a fields that is a List is added, say as per:-
data class Task(
    var task: String,
    var done: Boolean = false,
    val subtasks: List<Task> = emptyList()
)


note default to an emptyList added to simplify the TypeConverter (a List is not required) for the demo of the principle(s).

Then the existing TypeConverter, as above (due to the emptyList default), copes. i.e. The GSON should handle the JSON String. All Room cares about is storing/retrieving a String from/to the respective Task object.
However, if the Task is @Embedded then as there is the additional field/member and as it is not a type that can be handled by Room, then a TypeConverter would be required for the subtasks object/column that is a List, as the subtasks, due to Task being embedded.
